# unable to form structure and update flag value when any duplicate value present in name field

Tags: javascript

unable to form structure as expectedoutput and need to update the flag to true,when there is duplicate values present for name field

```js
let items = [{mnemonic:'first',name:'alm',flag:false},
             {mnemonic:'second',name:'old',flag: false},
             {mnemonic:'first',name:'newValue',flag: false},
             {mnemonic:'second',name:'newValue',flag: false}]


let expectedOutput = [{mnemonic:'first',name:'alm',flag:false},
             {mnemonic:'second',name:'old',flag: false},
             {mnemonic:'first',name:'newValue',flag: true},
             {mnemonic:'second',name:'newValue',flag: true}]


let newArr = items.map(i=> ({
  ...i,
  ...({flag:!items.some(_v=>_v.name == i.name)?true:false})
}))
  
  console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map` seems not really useful here as you need to modify all element which was already added in the array. Here is a simple `for` loop, also can be refactored to `forEach` if you would like to

```js
const newArr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  const repeatedElementIndex = newArr.findIndex(({ name }) => name === items[i].name);
  
  if (repeatedElementIndex !== -1) {
    newArr[repeatedElementIndex].flag = true;
    newArr.push({ ...items[i], flag: true });
  } else {
    newArr.push(items[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: how to ignore case for empty string  and null suppose if name="" or name=null

Comment: repeatedElementIndex !== -1 && items[i].name!=="" && items[i].name!==null